# jQuery - get contents of selected element (not html of its contents)

Tags: jquery

Say I have the following html:

`<div id="myDiv" title="My Div">This is me!</div>`

I want to write a jquery statement such that the result is the entire line above as a string.

I almost want something like:
`var selectedHtml = $("#myDiv").self();`  (I know that's not valid jquery) which results in `selectedHtml` having the value "`<div id="myDiv" title="My Div">This is me!</div>`"

Any ideas about which jquery function I'm looking for?

PS: getting the `.html()` of this node's `.parent()` will not work as it will give me siblings of the above node too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think might also be possible:

- `wrap` your div with another div (`<div id="wrapdiv" />`) --> [wrap()](http://api.jquery.com/wrap/)
- get the `html` on the wrapdiv
- `unwrap` the wrapdiv (so do `$("#myDiv").unwrap()`) --> [unwrap()](http://api.jquery.com/unwrap/)

Here is a live example: http://jsbin.com/oniki/edit

**edit:**

Perhaps this is better because it doesn't use an id for the wrapperdiv and therefore less change for bugs with existing ids:

- `wrap()` your div with another (nameless) div
- get the `html()` of the `parent()` of your div
- `unwrap()` your div

See it in action: http://jsbin.com/oniki/3/edit

Comment: I wonder how browsers handle it if you wrap an element in a `div` when that's not valid structure, like wrapping a `td`, `tr`, `li`, etc. Still, good thought and probably better than cloning.

Comment: @T.J. Crowder, I tried it with an unclosed `<li>` and firefox 3.6 handles it fine: `<li id="test">hello world</li>`

Comment: Yeah, as long as the OP tests it in their target browsers with the kinds of elements they're expecting to use, and it does work, this is my favorite approach.

Answer (score 3):

You can use plain javascript to do this.

```
var selectedHtml = document.getElementById ( "myDiv" ).outerHTML; //IE only
```

You can use this to get the outerHTML of a jquery element

```
jQuery.fn.outerHTML = function() {
    return $('<div>').append( this.eq(0).clone() ).html();
};
```

From

[jQuery Snippets: outerHTML](http://brandonaaron.net/blog/2007/06/17/jquery-snippets-outerhtml)

Comment: close, but this breaks down if I don't want the result as a `<div>`. What if the element I select is a `<tr>` and I don't want it wrapped in a `<div>`. Or am I missing something?

Comment: No you can call $("#myDiv").outerHTML() and you will get the desired result.

Comment: Here's what I meant - what if in my question the html in question was `<tr id="myTr" title="My Tr">This is my Tr</tr>`. Do you agree that `$("#myTr").outerHTML() will return the wrong result?

Comment: You can call this on any jQuery element.

Answer (score 0):

Found this - very complete, but I'm not sure if it's overkill...

```
jQuery.fn.extend( {
outerHtml: function( replacement )
{
 // We just want to replace the entire node and contents with
 // some new html value
 if (replacement)
 {
  return this.each(function (){ $(this).replaceWith(replacement); });
 }

 /*
  * Now, clone the node, we want a duplicate so we don't remove
  * the contents from the DOM. Then append the cloned node to
  * an anonymous div.
  * Once you have the anonymous div, you can get the innerHtml,
  * which includes the original tag.
  */
 var tmp_node = $("<div></div>").append( $(this).clone() );
 var markup = tmp_node.html();

 // Don't forget to clean up or we will leak memory.
 tmp_node.remove();
  return markup;
 }
});
```

http://ivorycity.com/blog/2009/08/18/3/

Answer (score 0):

You can already do this with standard jQuery with the following method:

If your element is:

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.mysite.com/"><span>This is my link</span></a>
```

And you want to get that exact outerhtml, you can use:

```
myhtml = $('<div>').append($('#myAnchor').eq(0).clone()).html());
alert(myhtml);
```

Without using any jquery plugins or anything. The alertbox will show:

```
<a id="myAnchor" href="http://www.mysite.com/"><span>This is my link</span></a>
```